# Is it logical to use the killall command to exit a script?

Tags: bash

I am working around with a pin generator and I have come across a small issue. 
I know of a few different methods to exiting a script but I have been playing around with calling the same script that is running as a child process, however when the child process is not called, the script exits perfectly. When called, the parent script does not exit properly after the child has completed and exited and the parent script loops back to the user input. I cannot think of anything other than possibly using the "wait" command though I don't know if this command would be proper with this code. Any thoughts on using the "killall" command to exit the script? I have tested it out, as you may see it in the code below, but I am left with the message, "Terminated" and if I can use killall how would I prevent that message from printing to standard out? Here is my code:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    clear
    echo ""
    echo "Now generating a random pin."
    sleep 3
    echo ""
    echo "----------------------------------------------"
    echo ""


    # Generates a random 8-digit number
    gen_num=$(tr -dc '0-9' </dev/urandom |  head -c 8)


    echo " Pin = $gen_num "
    echo ""
    echo "Pin has been generated!"
    sleep 3
    echo ""
    clear

    PS3="Would you like to generate another pin?: "
    select CHOICE in "YES" "NO"
    do

    if [ "$CHOICE" == "YES" ]
    then

    bash "/home/yokai/Modules/Wps-options.sh"

    elif [ "$CHOICE" == "NO" ]
    then

    clear
    echo ""
    echo "Okay bye!"
    sleep 3
    clear
    killall "Wps-options.sh"
    break
    exit 0

    fi
    done
    exit 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call the same script recursively (and then kill all its instances). The following script performs the task without forking:

```
#!/bin/bash
gen_pin () {
  echo 'Now generating a random pin.'
  # Generates a random 8-digit number
  gen_num="$(tr -dc '0-9' </dev/urandom | head -c 8)"
  echo "Pin = ${gen_num}"
  PS3='Would you like to generate another pin?:'
  select CHOICE in 'NO' 'YES'
  do 
    case ${CHOICE} in 
      'NO')
        echo 'OK'
        exit 0;;
      *) 
        break;;
    esac
  done
}  
while true
do
  gen_pin
done
```

You can find a lot of information about how to program in bash [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

Comment: 100% solution. Thank you very much Sir. This will reduce the resource cost in a very effective way. Kudos to you.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked for you! Take in mind that the select control structure is a LOOP too! The loop continues until a break (CTRL+C) is encountered, so you doesn't  need a while loop. Here is an [example](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Select_loop)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you execut

```
bash "/home/yokai/Modules/Wps-options.sh"
```

The script forks and crates a child process, then, it waits for the child termination, and it does not continue with execution, unless, your script **Wps-options.sh** executes something else in background (forking again) without reaping its child. But i can not tell you more because i dont know what is in your script **Wps-options.sh**

To prevent messages to be printed to stdout when you execute **killall**:

```
 killall "Wps-options.sh" 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

**1>** stands for stdout redirection to file **/dev/null** and **2>** stands for stderr redirection to file **/dev/null**

Comment: What is confusing me is, though the syntax is functional, after the child process ends and exits, the parent is intended to also end and exit but instead it is looping back to the user input. As of right now, this is the entire script. I am using it as a simple optional script to be called from another but I do not have the other calling this specific script yet. So the code I have posted here is the full code so far. Thank you for the stdout information. The only way the child should be forking a child of its own is if the "YES" option is run inside the child but I am not doing this yet.

Comment: Also the script Wps-options.sh is the code that i posted. It is running a second instance of itself as a child.

Comment: If you want to execute the same script again, but not create a child process, use `exec "$0"` -- this assumes your script is executable and can be found in the $PATH. Ref https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-exec